# difference in query result while using Model.find_by_query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails application, 
I am performing a union query using Model.find_by_query

Since tables have different number of columns, i am using virtual columns.

My query looks like

```
"SELECT id,  'N/a' AS start_time,  'N/a' AS end_time,  'N/a' AS 
STATUS , project_id, spent_on AS DATE, user_id, hours AS spent_time, comments AS 
COMMENT , activity_id
FROM table1
WHERE spent_on > DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL -30
DAY ) 
AND user_id =80
UNION (

SELECT id, start_time, end_time, 
STATUS , project_id, DATE, user_id, spent_time, 
COMMENT , activity_id
FROM table2
WHERE user_id =80
AND DATE > DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL -30 DAY )
)"
```

I am getting proper output when running the query in mysql, 
but running the same query with Model.find_by_sql gives me different output

This is the output i am getting running the query in mysql

[image]

while Model.find_by_sql() returns only few columns,

```
<Task id: 6153, start_time: "2000-01-01 00:00:00", end_time: "2000-01-01 00:00:00", project_id: 6, spent_time: 10.0, user_id: 80, activity_id: 9>
```

Also notice that there's also a mismatch in the values. instead of 'N/a' i am getting "2000-01-01 00:00:00" in time fields.

I figured out that 'N/A' is getting converted to "2000-01-01 00:00:00" because field type is time. so Rails converts it to some time value.

But can i override this?

How can i get desired output? any other way for executing such raw queries?

Comments please?

Thnx.

Comment: which version of rails you are working on ?

Comment: I figured out that the columns that were not matching with Model when performing Model.find_by_sql() were being ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so there are two issues that I can see here, one is that your result set is being typecast incorrectly, and the second is that some columns are missing.

You have two options as far as I can see for the typecasting problem:

1. Access the data without typecasting. Each attribute on a rails model has a corresponding '_before_type_cast' attribute (e.g. `task.start_date` and `task.start_date_before_type_cast`, `task.user_id` and `task.user_id_before_type_cast` etc), use these attributes instead and you should see **"N/A"** instead of **"2000-01-01 00:00:00"**
2. Use a different alias (e.g. SELECT "N/A" as new_start_date) that way rails should read it as a raw column and won't do any typecasting on it.

For you second issue, whilst the columns may not appear to be there, that's only because the `inspect` method (which is what prints out the code you put above) only know about columns on the task database table, not the columns in your SQL query. However the data is there and can be accessed like any other attribute.

```
>> results = Model.find_by_sql('SELECT columns FROM table WHERE conditions')
>> results[0]
=> <Task id: 6153, start_time: "2000-01-01 00:00:00", end_time: "2000-01-01 00:00:00", project_id: 6, spent_time: 10.0, user_id: 80, activity_id: 9>
>> results[0].comment
=> "test"
```

Comment: Wow. that was very useful. thnx a lot. one thing i noticed that Rails considers field names case sensitively. the same query was running in database(mysql) because there field names are case insensitive by default in mysql. Now as mentioned in your answer results[0].COMMENT worked for me. because in query i had 'COMMENT' and  not 'comment'